# What's wrong with the multi-threaded code?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my Server class, I have the following code.
Why the execution flow never reaches the while loop in the Server class?

```
// Server
public class Server {
    public void start(String remote, int rport) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Source(this)).start();

            ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
                ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(clientSocket, this);
                System.out.println("sdssssaafffffaddfasfd");
                new Thread(connection).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Listen socket:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

In the Source class which implements Runnable I have:

```
public class Source implements Runnable {
    private final Server server;

    public Source(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Viewer myViewer = new Viewer();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Stream Viewer");
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(myViewer);

        OpenIMAJGrabber grabber = new OpenIMAJGrabber();
        Device device = null;
        Pointer<DeviceList> devices = grabber.getVideoDevices();
        for (Device d : devices.get().asArrayList()) {
            device = d;
            break;
        }

        boolean started = grabber.startSession(320, 240, 30, Pointer.pointerTo(device));
        if (!started) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not able to start native grabber!");
        }

        while (true) {
            // code runs infinitely here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two while loops in this example, which one do you mean?

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: If you mean the `while` loop in your first code block, how do you know it's not getting there? Maybe it's just waiting for a connection. `accept` is a blocking operation...

Comment: It's worth looking at a stack dump (use `jps`/`jstack` or `ctrl-break`/`ctrl-\` in the console window). (My guess is you block somewhere in the constructor of `Source`.)

Comment: @Lokesh No. The loop in Source execute infinitely.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I'm using IntelliJ, no idea how to do that.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline  This is the constructor of Source class "private final Server server;

    public LocalImageSource(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    } }"

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline It shouldn't block cuz the code in Source run again and again.

Comment: @luckykevin : When you say Source, do you mean look in Source.java class. It runs a separate thread , so should not stop control from moving beyond "new Thread(new Source(this)).start();" . You shld share whole of code including Source.java to take this further.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? It should get to the while-loop in the server class.

Comment: (Probably not the problem, but you shouldn't touch Swing off the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).)

Comment: Hey, there actually can be a racing condition with threads. In this code-block while (true) { // code runs infinitely here...} in the source. If this thread does not sleep and performs actions without any stop, it can block other threads (+ server thread) from running. You should really try to remove this loop from Source and see if it works.

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev I tried sleep for 1000ms, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev I set breakpoints at both while loops. It just doesn't goes out of the Source loop.

Comment: @luckykevin, Try to debug with System.out.println() - call it once in the server while loop before accept. Does it work?

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev That is the problem. It actually execute in the while loop. but it is waiting for connection. How stupid I am. I forgot to start the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th problem is with the debugging method here. Using the debugger without the client connection will not proceed further than the first call to the `accept()` method. In order find out the problem, you need to put one `System.out.println()` statement inside the `Server` `while`-loop before the call to `accept()` and check if the loop is entered.

Answer (score 0):

A guess, but with swing one needs to ensure that event handling is done in the correct thread.

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Stream Viewer");
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(myViewer);
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should it matter? if he does "new Thread(new Source(this)).start()"

Comment: @ArtemMoskalev yes I am proved wrong. And indeed my own practice is to give an output message _before_ an accept.